# tibco deploy command line fail

Tags: linux, terminal, command-line, tibco-business-works

I want deploy application [Tibco BisunessWork6](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/activematrix_businessworks/6.6.1/doc/html/GUID-EC830BFA-2C63-4B5D-835B-FD6DF0B94D72.html).

This is official command:

```
bwadmin Command Line

When using the deploy command, the EAR filename is the relative location of the archive with respect to the BW_HOME\domains\domain_name\archives folder. For example, if MyDomain contains the AppSpace to deploy to and the archive file is located in the BW_HOME\domains\MyDomain\archivesdirectory, do not specify a qualifier for the archive file location.

Execute the following command from the command line to deploy an uploaded application archive to MyAppSpace:

BW_HOME\bin>bwadmin deploy -d MyDomain -a MyAppSpace tibco.bw.sample.binding.rest.BookStore.application_1.0.0.ear
```

This is my command:

```
BW_HOME\bin>bwadmin deploy -d E_INT -a ct ct01.application_1.0.0.ear

err
TIBCO-BW-ADMIN-CLI-500402: Failed to deploy application from the archive [ct01.appcation_1.0.0.ear],
TIBCO-BW-ADMIN-500418: Application archive file [ct01.application_1.0.0.ear] not found in the domain [E_INT]
```

my dir:

```
E_INT 
  appspaces
  appnodes
  archives
```

archives is not inside appspace

I tried these, but they all fail:

```
BW_HOME\bin>bwadmin deploy -d E_INT -a archives ct01.application_1.0.0.ear
BW_HOME\bin>bwadmin deploy -d E_INT -a ct /BW_HOME/bin/E_INT/archives/ct01.application_1.0.0.ear
BW_HOME\bin>bwadmin deploy -d E_INT -a ct ../archives/ct01.application_1.0.0.ear
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming question but one with the installation or use of some existing software, making your question off-topic here. Please start with the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Before deploying you must first upload the archive.

The command to use are the following:

upload -d <DOMAIN_NAME> -r

Example:

upload -d TESTEM -r C:/tibco/BW6/Installation/Tests/Build/Subscriber.application_1.0.0.ear
TIBCO-BW-ADMIN-CLI-300410: Uploaded archive [C:/Extra/BW6/Installation/Tests/Build/Subscriber.application_1.0.0.ear].

deploy --d <DOMAIN_NAME> -a <APPSPACE_NAME> -r <APPLICATION_NAME>

Example :

bwadmin[admin]> deploy -d TESTEM  -a AS05 -r Subscriber.application_1.0.0.ear
TIBCO-BW-ADMIN-CLI-300403: Deployed application [Subscriber.application:1.0].